# Prove that ${\xi_i}$ is complete system in $l_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> Let ${\{x_i\}} \subset \mathbb{C}$, $x_i \neq 0$, $x_i \rightarrow 0$, $|x_i| < 1$.
>   $\xi_i$ = {$x^k_i$}$_{k\ge0} \Rightarrow$ {$\xi_i$} is complete system of sequences in $l_2$.

I should prove that every Cauchy sequence converges in $l_2$. But from definition $x_i \rightarrow 0$, why it's not enough for the proof?
Or should I find clojure of {$\xi_i$} in $l_2$(then {$\xi_i$} is dence in $l_2$).
If I'm right, what should I do next?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. $\{\xi_i\}$ is a sequence in $\ell_2$. What do you mean by calling it "a complete system"? In order for it to be a complete subset of $\ell_2$ it would have to have all of its convergent subsequences converge to members of itself. But, $\{\xi_i\}$ converges to the $0$ sequence, which is not a member of $\{\xi_i\}$. Thus it is not complete in that sense. So what did you mean?